# How to add text in Calendar view date box

Tags: android

I was wondering if it was possible to add text in a date box of the CalendarView?
If not, how could I achieve this without creating my own view from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add text to in a date box of the CalendarView .you have to customise the calendar view. here are two examples 
https://github.com/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View
https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-android-custom-calendar-view-with-events/